# How to handle encryption key with a large development team?

Tags: programming-practices, encryption

If we have a large development team, say 100, and we would like to keep our encryption key hidden from developers who are not directly involved in the encryption module/algorithm, what are some best practices to keep this key as secret as possible while still allowing for development and debugging?

Comment: Can't you just generate a key for development/debugging and then later generate one for production?

Comment: No, testing involves the entire system, the key would be used in multiple products.

Comment: What kind of key are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

The Apache foundation has a pretty simple yet effective way to handle this. The encryption key (or code signing cert) lives in a separate repository only accessible by the trusted and the BuildBot. When building the bits that need the key, the bot checks it out -- or more properly just downloads it -- and includes it in the appropriate place in the solution. You get change control and security while not interrupting the modern development practice.

All that said, I would address the underlying problem of not being able to fob the encryption key off to infrastructure that dev never has to see.